# Not receiving results, outputs or any errors with LIKE query in Laravel

Tags: laravel-7

Could someone please assist as I am trying to do a `LIKE` query using Laravel but it doesn't seem to output any results (or errors) when returning the view. The view only returns with the search field (form). Any assistance or advice would be appreciated.

**Controller**

```
public function search()
{
    $input = Request::get('name');
    $properties = Property::where('title', 'like', '%' . $input . '%');

    return view('index', ['properties' => $properties]);
}
```

**View**

```php
@foreach($properties as $property)
    <tr class="item{{$property->id}}">
        <td>{{$property->title}}</td>
    </tr>
@endforeach
```

Comment: Thank you very much! I have added the ->get() in the query   {
    $input = Request::get('name');
    $properties = Property::where('title','like','%'.$input.'%')->get();
    return view('index',['properties' => $properties]);
  }

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `$properties = Property::where('title','like','%'.$input.'%');` is only adding a `where` clause to the query, not getting any data. Replace it with

```
$properties = Property::where('title','like','%'.$input.'%')->get();
```

to return the results from the query. (Added `->get()` to the query)

https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/queries#where-clauses

Comment: Thank you very much! It is now displaying the results.